# Get percentage of values in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, analytics, periscope

**If this question is asked or referenced somewhere else, please refer me to that place**

I am trying to get the percentage of how many New users of the total count of users and display that in a pie chart using Periscopedata(Sisense).

```
select
  investments
  , case
    when investments > 1
      then 'returning user'
    else 'new user'
  end as "N or R"
from
  investments_count
group by
  investments
```

The return table is returning the right values, but the pie chart is returning the wrong percentage (should be 29% instead of 2%). I'm not sure how to edit that.

Thank you for the help.

**investments count**

[image]

**new vs repeat**

[image]

**Pie Chart result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select investments
       avg(case when investments = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_new_user
from investments_count
group by investments
```